# Conics Section: Equation of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

I have a question that states

> Find the equation of a circle with center $(2,-3)$ and passing through $(3, -5)$.

I arrived at $x^2 + y^2 -4x + 6y - 5 = 0 $. It was marked wrong. The answer is said to be $x^2 + y^2 -4x + 6y +8 = 0$.

My question is isn't the approach of solving this question same as $(x -a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (x₁-a)^2 + (y₁-b)^2$ where $(a,b)$ is the coordinate of the center of the circle and $(x_1, y_1)$ is the coordinate of the point.

Comment: It seems that you've forgotten the $a^2$ and $b^2$ terms from $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$ somewhere in your manipulation.

Comment: Yes, you want to simplify $(x -a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (x_1-a)^2 + (y_1-b)^2$. If you want to know where you went wrong, show your calculations step by step. My guess is you forgot to include the constant terms on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle has the equation

$$(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=r^2,$$

where $r$ is unknown. The point $(3,-5)$ is on the circle, hence

$$(3-2)^2+(-5+3)^2=r^2.$$

This gives $r^2=5.$

Hence

$$(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=5$$

or

$$x^2 + y^2 -4x +6y +8 =0.$$

Answer (score 2):

For a quick check,

$$3^2+(-5)^2-4\cdot3+6(-5)-5\ne 0$$

and

$$3^2+(-5)^2-4\cdot3+6(-5)+8=0.$$

---

The constant term in the equation must be

$$a^2+b^2-(x_1-a)^2-(y_1-b)^2=4+9-1-4=8.$$

As noticed by others,

$$-1-4=-5.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the formula
$$
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = (x_1-a)^2+(y_1-b)^2
$$
where $(a,b)$ is the centre of the circle and $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point that lies on the circle. This formula works because the RHS tells you the length of the $\text{radius}^2$, which is what you need. Hence, the equation of the circle is
$$
(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=(3-2)^2+(-5+3)^2=5 \, .
$$
If we expand the brackets, we get
$$
x^2-4x+4+y^2+6y+9=5
$$
which simplifies to the textbook answer.

---

Personally, I prefer methods that require less memorisation. Hence, if I was solving this question, I would find the length of the radius using the distance formula, and then write the equation of the circle in the form
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 \, ,
$$
before expanding the brackets if necessary.